# Modal Logic: ◊-Distribution

Tags: logic, modal-logic

It's a theorem of K that $\diamond$ distributes to disjuncts and vice versa:

$$\diamond(p \lor q) ≡ \diamond p \lor \diamond q$$

Does it distribute to negated disjuncts? Is the following a licit proof in K?

1. $\diamond(p → q)$
2. $\diamond(\lnot p\lor q)$                 -------------  Def. of material implication
3. $\diamond \lnot p \lor \diamond q$                  --------------   ◊ - distribution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can substitute ~□~  for ⋄ and prove the above in K. No D required.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so far so good. The rule is better put schematically rather than by using propositional atoms, i.e. the rule is

$$\diamond(\alpha \lor \beta) \equiv (\diamond\alpha \lor \diamond\beta) \text{ for all wffs }\alpha, \beta$$

This makes it clear the rule applies generally, not just to propositional atoms, as perhaps using $p, q$ misleading suggests.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that does make it more clear.